# How to recover a hacked gmail account?

Tags: gmail, android

I posted on Google Gmail support forums and one person answered telling me to try the recovery again and after 24 hours and many other tries none else answers.

You can never be sure how you got hacked, but I strongly believe my password was stolen because I was using a public wi-fi in my university (there are 200 people in my class). My android phone, while I was surfing the web decided to load the emails. This gave to the hacker my password as he/she was on the same network.

Other than the fact I have important information in this gmail, I don't understand why a classmate would hack my phone and I am really serious what he/she is trying to do with my account.

What can I do to get my gmail account back?

Comment: @Devid: Thanks for the edit but I need to add the thread title, so someone can look at the post.

Comment: But there is no link to the thread. Try this maybe it helps: https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2943007?rd=1

Comment: @Devid: thanks, I tried this but nothing. You can find the thread here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/gmail/report-an-issue

Comment: @Luka - What do you mean almost all of the questions? You need to answer all the questions with the correct answer. There really isn't anything more you can do, you started the recover process, there isn't another method that Google has provided. This is the reason the Google Authenticator and other security measures are offered ( i.e. the ability to recover the account through a SMS message ).

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as an answer here.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thanks for the reply. I expect/hope a Google engineer will see this and do something about it. The forum is really not much help and I have very few options left.

Comment: Might as well take an advert out in your local newspaper, as far as I can tell. Just because you're desperate doesn't mean that this is a useful approach, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right, but what's a useful approach then? I have 4 options: a) ask on the Google forums (done), b) talk to the police (I will do it), c) talk to the university (same as b, because most likely they will talk to the police), d) go to the Google offices in my country (I will do it).

Comment: You forgot `e) Cross your fingers`, `f) ????` and `g) PROFIT!!!!`

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: lol :P Maybe I should sleep and tomorrow a brighter day will start...

Comment: @Luka Let's hope so!

Comment: Even with the edit, it's off topic for Super User. You can try Web Apps, but I'm pretty sure they'd just tell you to talk to Google

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't do much if the official form for resetting/recovering the gmail account which can be found [**here**](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2943007?rd=1#ts=2402623) or [**here**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270?hl=en) can't help you.

If nothing helps, you can try as last hope to send a email to your hacked account and negotiate with the hacker (if the content of your account is so important to you). You might also contact Google via phone  for more information, although it may be that they also can't help you.

If you manage somehow to get access to your account back don't forget to check all the settings and also set 2-step-verification for more security.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I called google but I never managed to talk to a human. Many people are/were in the same situation as me and a google engineer saw the correct answers they had on the recovery process and returned their account back.

Comment: So have you answered correct your answers and got your account back ?

Comment: I answered almost all the questions correctly but the recovery doesn't give back my account. I can only hope someone from Google will check the answered questions and understand I am the owner. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are resetting your account you have to have set up account recovery options, else it won't work. 
Yes, actually you just have to prove that you are the owner. So even if the hacker changed the questions and answers someone at Google can see what the answers/questions were prior to the change and recover your account I think. If you manage to get your account back don't forget to post back and tell us how.

Comment: Okay, I will, and I am sure I will get it back!

Comment: @Ramhound: I mean I don't remember what month I made the account, because the account was made 4 years back. How can google expect me to remember this?

Comment: @Luka its in their privacy statement that it is the only way they can help you. They expect you to use a question/answer that you can remember or write down. Or as stated earlier, use a different security measure such as Google authenticate or sms verification.

Comment: @LPChip: Thanks for the reply, I know that they need me to answer the recovery questions and I did it. I don't remember everything, but like many other people, if someones seems the account will understand that answering almost all the questions proves I am the owner.